# Setting some textboxes in beamer slides

Tags: beamer, header-footer, templates

I'm creating a beamer template for my university. I have some problem with making this template adjustable for everyone. I want to create some texboxes at the footer and header ribbons to make students able to write their name, department's name, slide number, and their presentation titles into them (on every slides except fist slide and with changing slide number). This should be adjustable for them since every person has a unique name, department name, and presentation title with different length. I have attached the background image [(look at image here(tue_‎background-1‎.jpg))](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inFUA.jpg) for beamer template with the specified textbox locations. Also you can find the MWE below:

```
‎\documentclass{beamer}‎

‎\usepackage{xcolor}‎
‎\usefonttheme{serif}‎
‎\usepackage[british]{babel}‎
‎\usepackage{graphicx,hyperref,url}‎
‎‎\usepackage{xepersian}‎
\settextfont{XB Niloofar.ttf}‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎

‎\setbeamerfont{block title}{size={}}‎
\setbeamersize{text margin right=2.1cm}‎
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vskip1.1cm\insertframetitle\par\small\insertframesubtitle}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]‎

% ‎Background‎
‎\makeatletter‎
‎\newlength\beamerleftmargin‎
‎\setlength\beamerleftmargin{\Gm@lmargin}‎
‎\makeatother‎
\usebackgroundtemplate‎
{
‎\hspace*{-1.1cm}%‎
‎\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth‎ , ‎height=\paperheight]{tue_‎background-1‎.jpg}‎
}

% ‎Navigation symbols‎
‎\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}‎

% ‎Themes‎
‎\useinnertheme[shadow=true]{rounded}‎


% ‎Colors‎
\usecolortheme{orchid}‎
\usecolortheme{whale}‎
‎\definecolor{tuelightblue}{cmyk}{0.2‎, ‎0.15‎, ‎0.04‎,  ‎0.0}‎
‎\definecolor{tueblue}{cmyk}{1.0‎, ‎0.93‎, ‎0.18‎, ‎0.05}‎
‎\definecolor{tuepurple}{cmyk}{0.14‎, ‎0.97‎, ‎0.51‎, ‎0.01}‎
\definecolor{babypink}{rgb}{0.96‎, ‎0.76‎, ‎0.76}‎

‎\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=tueblue,bg=tuelightblue}‎
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=}‎
\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{fg=tueblue,bg=} % !<#> is transparency‎
‎\setbeamercolor{palette secondary}{fg=tueblue‎, ‎bg=tuelightblue}
\setbeamercolor{palette tertiary}{fg=tuelightblue,bg=tueblue}
‎\setbeamercolor{palette quaternary}{fg=tuepurple,bg=tuepurple}
‎\setbeamercolor{example text}{fg=tuepurple‎, ‎bg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{footline}{fg=tuepurple‎, ‎bg=}‎

\usefoottemplate{%‎
‎\vbox to 9.5pt{%‎
\hspace{10.07cm}‎
‎{\bf {\color{tuelightblue} \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber}}‎
}
}


‎\begin{document}‎


‎\begin{frame}‎
\begin{exampleblock}{purpose of investigation‎}

‎\end{exampleblock}‎
‎\end{frame}‎
\end{document}‎
```

Comment: Please helpppp...

Comment: Please add a sketch how the result should look like and make the code a mimimal working example, e.g. not using any unnecessary  fonts which prevents users from compiling your code if they don't have them.